# Wordpress : PHP Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, printf

I have this warning :

```
PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/widgets.php on line 1193
```

This is the function it refers to in widgets.php :

```
function the_widget( $widget, $instance = array(), $args = array() ) {
    global $wp_widget_factory;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_widget_factory->widgets[ $widget ] ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong(
            __FUNCTION__,
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: register_widget() */
                __( 'Widgets need to be registered using %s, before they can be displayed.' ),
                '<code>register_widget()</code>'
            ),
            '4.9.0'
        );
        return;
    }

    $widget_obj = $wp_widget_factory->widgets[ $widget ];
    if ( ! ( $widget_obj instanceof WP_Widget ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $default_args          = array(
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    );
    $args                  = wp_parse_args( $args, $default_args );
    $args['before_widget'] = sprintf( $args['before_widget'], $widget_obj->widget_options['classname'] );
    
    $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance );

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php */
    $instance = apply_filters( 'widget_display_callback', $instance, $widget_obj, $args );

    if ( false === $instance ) {
        return;
    }
```

The line 1193 of widget.php is :

$args['before_widget'] = sprintf( $args['before_widget'], $widget_obj->widget_options['classname'] );

I don't know how to resolve it, i'm affraid of doing something wrong because I'm novice in php and the function wasn't created or modified by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem by myself by adding an id in the line :

```
$args['before_widget'] = sprintf( $args['before_widget'], $widget_obj->id , $widget_obj->widget_options['classname'] );
```

I don't know why or where but $args['before_widget'] return :

```
'<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">'
```

So it needed 2 args so I just add $widget_obj->id and I don't any error message !
I hope it would help someone someday :)